# Django - 'module' object has no attribute 'BigIntegerField'

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm building a form. It has a field `a = forms.BigIntegerField()`. While running it says `'module' object has no attribute 'BigIntegerField'` . I viewed the [Django Documents](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/), but there still seems to be `BigIntergetField`, still I'm getting this error. Why?

Comment: Paste your full form class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BigIntegerField` is a [Model field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#bigintegerfield), not a Form field

In the form you just use `forms.IntegerField`:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#integerfield